# ios revoke push notification certificate

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have an app already on apple store and it uses push notification. Now I am about to submit a new version, and I would like to make some changes to the push notification certificate, i.e. I need to revoke the certificate and recreate a new one. My question is, would the revoke affect the push function of my current app on apple store? Will push still be working fine?

Answer (score 4):

No. You can regenerate your certificates at any time, this will affect the program only for the period when you update your certificate on server

Comment: can u provide your answer with link , from apple document maybe ?

Comment: Apple documentation doesn't cover this question, but this is quite obvious, since push certificate is for your server's needs. App cannot Send push notifications by itself, that must be done with some server code, that connects to gateway.push.apple.com with your certificate provided.

I did my certificate renew after an expiry several times without any problems.

Comment: mark this question as resolved if your problem is solved, so other users could find this answer in the future.